# I can't install or update my sdk components in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, emulation, android-virtual-device, android-sdk-manager

hello everybody
I want to create an emulator in avd manager but there is no system images for creating it, after refreshing the page it's still not recommending any system image for downloading.

I opened the sdk manager for installing system manager but i can't update it, in sdk update site list i got this   [image: error message].

How can i change my sdk update site to install new component ?

Thank you.

Comment: please help me :(

Comment: It looks like it's got a network issue connecting to the google site. If you're at a work site, you're likely to have a web proxy that you'll need to configure via HTTP Proxy settings.  (that's what usually causes problems for me updating things like this at work).

Comment: i use psiphon but it's still not working

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows try to run Android Studio as admin.
I also had problem downloading any resource if I didn't run Android Studio with run as admin option.
Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Have you tried to download resources from SDK Tools just beside the SDK Update Sites tab? @EdoFaroqi

Comment: I think you are supposed to download resources in SDK Tools, check Android Emulator there @EdoFaroqi